# field_view_value returns null for boolean field

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a custom field `field_sold` which contains a single boolean value. I'm trying to use the following function to retrieve the content of the field, but it always seems to return null:

```
function <theme>_render_field($node, $field_name, $delta = 0, $display = array()) {
   $field = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
   $field = field_view_value('node', $node, $field_name, $field[$delta], $display);
   return render($field);  
}
```

When trying to dumping the `$field` variable between the calls to `field_get_items()` and `field_view_value()` I recieve the following output:

```
// after field_get_items()
Array ( [0] => 
   Array ( [value] => 1 ) ) 
// after field_view_value()
Array ( [#markup] => [#access] => 1 )
```

When I'm using the above function for other fields it works as expected, for instance when rendering a image field like this:

```
print <theme>_render_field($node, 'field_image', 0, 
                     array('type' => 'image', 
                           'settings' => array(
                           'image_style' => 'object_200x300',
                           'image_link' => 'content')
                           ));
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually rendering it and haven't forgotten to `echo`?

Comment: @Clive - Yes, I'm very sure. I event tried to cast it to an int before printing like: `print intval(<theme>_render_field($node, 'field_sold'));`

Comment: @Clive - I updated my question.

Comment: At a guess, the `$display` settings your passing in for the bool field are off somewhere - what are you passing for that?

Comment: @Clive - I'm using the default value for the `display` argument: `print <theme>_render_field($node, 'field_sold');`

Comment: The default is an empty array though - is that definitely what a boolean field needs for display? (I haven't checked, it's just a thought)

Comment: @Clive - Without any luck I have tried to find a complete list of different formatters that could be used with the `field_view_value()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
$display['type'] = 'list_key';
```

in your theme function to get not null key of field. Or create own formatter, for ex.

```
function mymodule_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
      'my_formatter' => array(
          'label' => t('My formatter'),
          'field types' => array('list_boolean'),
      ),
  );
}


function mymodule_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'my_formatter':
      foreach($items as $delta => $item) {
        $value = $item['value'] == 1 ? '<span class="">ON TEXT</span>' : '<span class="">OFF TEXT</span>';
        $element[$delta] = array(
            '#markup' => $value,
        );
      }
      break;
  }

  return $element;
}
```

and after that set

```
$display['type'] = 'my_formatter';
```

in Your theme function